# How do I resolve a DHCP issue with a fon router?

Tags: router, dhcp

I don't know how many people are familiar with [fon](http://fon.com/) (this is totally not a plug, because it basically doesn't work ever) but I've been using a WRT54G router from fon with the final fon firmware for 4 years now, and a Fonera (1) for 3 years. I never used to get anyone using my Fon router, and I thought the Fonera would solve this, as it auto updates itself and apparently there were quirks frequently.

My fonera has never had a paying user nor a free user, but it's not because people don't connect to it. I've tried connecting to it myself, and the problem seems to be that the DHCP server is acting badly. Shortly after my first request and [redirection](https://www.fon.com/login/gateway/sec/dcfa87dc546dab200c9b9b67761705e8?res=notyet&uamip=192.168.182.1&uamport=3990&challenge=3183f8aec2cfebb5da970a3c5c56f398&mac=00-25-00-3E-50-99&ip=192.168.182.71&nasid=00-18-84-24-11-35&userurl=http%3a%2f%2fnypl.org%2f), I get messages like:

```
IP 192.168.187.71 is in use by 00:0c:29:mac:address.
```

But my wireless mac address is 00:25:00:something. Does this happen to anyone else? How would I solve this issue?

Perhaps there's a way I could use a custom OpenWRT firmware to enable people to use my fon gateway while retaining better control over the actual behavior. This is something I'd love to have working right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like your firmware is probably behaving properly and you do have a legitimate IP conflict.  Do you have a VMWare instance running anywhere on your home network?  That's who owns the `00:0c:29` MAC prefix...

Comment: I am running a VMWare instance on the same machine. It is asleep. It does not conflict when I switch my SSID to my other router running a stock Linksys firmware.

Comment: Hold on for a sec... What machine is giving you the IP addres conflict message?  If it's your laptop, then it's not the DHCP server's fault.  It can't control whether or not another device on the network is holding on to an IP after it should have let it go.  The "ip in use" message indicates that your host OS is actually still seeing some sort of traffic from the VMWare instance.  Duplicate ARP responses or something...

Comment: The laptop, running OS X and vmware in the background, is showing the conflict. My point is this conflict doesn't occur on any other router or network. I believe that the Fonera's DHCP server is handing out the same IP to both Mac OS and VMware's bridged network adapter, despite having different mac addresses, and that this isn't normal behavior. Taking VMWare's Windows 7 out of sleep it now alerted me to having a IP conflict too. Although this doesn't happen when not connecting to the Fonera.

Comment: My next step would be a wireshark session.  Watch for when each assignment is handed out.  Also watch to see if the router makes any attempt to ping or arp the IP before assigning it.  It still sounds to me like the router may be behaving in an acceptable, but not optimal, way.

Comment: Also watch to see if either your OS X laptop or the Windows 7 VMWare instance attempt to renew their lease once its expired or if they just assume it's still available and began asnwering ARP requests.